# Using ubuntu pro with frozen machine

Tags: xps

I just signed up for Ubuntu Pro but I'm not sure how to proceed. My Ubuntu box freezes up almost immediately after I log on (no response to keyboard, mouse, touchpad). So my question is, how can I access Ubuntu Pro support through another machine?

The problem machine is Dell XPS 13 9315 with Dell-provided Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Comment: Ubuntu Pro is a Canonical provided & supported product, Ubuntu *community* are not involved in that support; though many are no doubt users of it. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is still a *supported* product, so you can ask questions about that product here, but Ubuntu Pro support is provided by Canonical (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-pro-faq/34042 maybe helpful)

Comment: Can you access a TTY console by pressing CTRL+ALT+f4 and then signing in with your username and password? Also, have you tried booting up with an older kernel? What about rescue mode?

Comment: Also also, have you tried logging in as guest? If you can log in as a guest account, this indicates there's something likely wrong with your user's configurations that is causing the freeze so then we will know where to start working on the problem from.

Comment: Was your Ubuntu system freezing before signing up for Pro? Are you saying that signing up for Pro is related to the freezing?

Comment: At user535733: No. the problem, thanks to Dell nonsupport, has existed since early Dec. I just signed up for Pro today to see if they might help.

Comment: At guiverc--Yeah, I know they're different. I just thought someone here might know about navigating Pro. I'll check the FAQ you mentioned.

Comment: As I read the FAQ that guiverc mentioned I realized I may have misunderstood what Pro is.

Comment: The free tier of Pro does NOT have professional support. The paid tier has a support contact whose contact information you would already have. Why not just use Ubuntu's free volunteer community support to help you? We are nice.

Comment: At user535733: I may post a new question. I think i've figured out that it's the SDD bone bad, but it won't hurt to run it by people. I'll probably post a question tomorrow, if I do so.
Thanks.

Comment: That is indeed one possible cause. Look up how to run a SMART test to be sure.